# Extract the SITEMAP of a web site

Tags: web, sitemap, extract

I want to extract the SITEMAP of any website (the hierarchy of the links between web pages of the same site).

How can I do this?

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=create+sitemap

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a web crawler: see this link [Writing a web crawler in c#](http://www.thecodinghumanist.com/Content/HowToWriteAWebCrawlerInCSharp.aspx)